# why this javascript code is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Do you know why this is failing, I mean alert is working (it shows me that if found the button) but text or background is not changed:

```
    $('input[type=button]').click( function() {

    var button=document.getElementsByName("contactme");
    alert(button.length + " elements!");
    button.value="New Button Text";
   button.style.backgroundImage="url(some_real_gif);"
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" name="contactme" value="test"/>
```

Thanks...

I have to use plain java script not jQuery..

Comment: *"I have to use plain java script not jQuery.."* Then why is there jQuery code in your question?

Comment: if you aren't supposed to use jQuery then why are you using it to select the button and attach the click function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `var button=document.getElementsByName("contactme");` would return an array of elements. Try:

```
var button=document.getElementsByName("contactme")[0];
```

Comment: A [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.getElementsByName) in fact, but yes, that's the problem.

Answer (score 6):

You're setting `value` and `style` of a NodeList.  `getElementsByName` can retrieve multiple elements, as the `name` attribute does not have to be unique in the document (the clue's in the name!) Setting these has no effect -- it doesn't affect the properties of the element(s) within the NodeList.

Either loop through the element(s) manually (using a `for` loop) or fully use jQuery:

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function () {
    var buttons = $('input[name="contactme"]');
    alert(buttons.length + " elements!");
    buttons.val("New Button Text");
    buttons.css({backgroundImage: "url(some_real_gif)"});
});
```

See the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com):

- [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val)
- [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css)
- [attribute-equals selector (`[name="value"]`)](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector)

Comment: I was in the process of typing exactly the same code (even down to renaming "button" to "buttons").  :)

Comment: Be sure to add a tag name or some other selector before an attribute filter lest you add days to your purgatorial suffering. ;o) `$('input[name="contactme"]');`

Comment: @patrick dw Which presumably consists of being forced to use browsers that don't implement `querySelectorAll`. Done--thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByName` will return a nodeList but `value` and `style` are properties of HTMLElementNodes. You have to loop over the list to get them.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function() {
     $("#contactme").val('New Button Text').css('background-image', 'url(some_real_gif)');
});
```

You would need to make sure the button id matches the name...

Comment: If there's more than one button with the same name, the IDs can't match (at least not if you want valid HTML).

Comment: True, but why would you want to have more than one button with the same name?

Comment: Because you have server-side code that performs some action based on which button was clicked, and switching on the value of `button_name` is simpler than checking whether `this_button_name` or `that_button_name` had a value submitted.  Not necessarily saying that's what's going on here, but the fact that the code is spitting out how many buttons it found makes it look like there may be more than one.

Answer (score 0):

Because button is a list of elements (even if it is a list of one)

What you can do is use `button[0].value` and `button[0].style.background`

Or use a jQuery solution:

To change only clicked button:

```
$('input[type=button]').click( function() 
{
    $(this).val("New Button Text");
   $(this).css('background-image','url("some_real_gif")');
});
```

To change all buttons:

```
$('input[type=button]').click( function() 
{
   $('input[type=button]').each(function(){
        $(this).val("New Button Text");
        $(this).css('background-image','url("some_real_gif")');
    });
});
```